# Question about linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S: R^2 \rightarrow R^2 $  be a linear operator such that $ S^2 = S$ and $ S\not= 0, S \not= I$. Prove that exists a ordered basis $B$ such that $ [S]_B = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)$.
Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: The more general result in any finite dimension was covered in the answer to [Basis of a projection](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73154/basis-of-a-projection).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** if $S^2 = S$, what can the eigenvalues of $S$ be?

Comment: We haven't seen eigenvalues yet...

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\ne0$ so that $x\ne S(x)\ne0$. We prove that $\mathcal B=(S(x),x-S(x))$ is linearly independent family so it's a basis for $\Bbb R^2$. In fact for $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$\alpha S(x)+\beta(x-S(x))=0$$
and by applying $S$ we get successively $\alpha=0$ and then $\beta=0$. The matrix of $S$  relative to the basis $\mathcal B$ has the desired form.

Answer (score 1):

Show that $\ker S = {\cal R} (I-S)$.

Then $\ker S$ cannot be $\{0\}$ as this would imply $S=I$ and
$\ker S$ cannot be $\mathbb{R}^2$ as this would imply $S=0$.

Hence there is some vector $v_2$ such that $S v_2 = 0$.

We know that there is some other vector $v$ such that $S v \neq 0$ (otherwise ...), so let
$v_1 = S v$. Note that $S v_1 = v_1$.

Show that $v_1,v_2$ form a basis, and determine $S$ in this basis.